# When was the ETH contract called?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

I have learned about Solidity development for several days. But for now, I have one confusing thing, and I don't know whether I am right or wrong. I searched Google, but I couldn't find anything. Maybe I search with the wrong keys. If you know that, please help me. Thank you, guys.
My question is, "When was the ETH contract called" I think the contract was called or said it was run code when the miner packed it. Am I right? When we make a transaction, it will be located in the pending poll. When the miner packed the block, it will run the contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contract is "executed" when it gets accepted into a block, and when that block is accepted. The process of submitting a transaction is as follows:

1. The transaction is generated and signed by the wallet
2. The signed transaction is sent to an Ethereum node
3. The signed transaction is added to the *mempool*. The mempool is where signed transactions are stored until they are included in a block.
4. The transaction is included in a block. Transactions in a block are executed in the order that miners decide.
5. The block is mined, and then the changes that are made by that transaction take effect.

Comment: If this has helped, then please mark this as the answer. Thanks!